# I need a good way to classify files names in each categories from an array in javascript, but when not having a match put into a general group

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Basically, I have two arrays, one is the types of the files and the other is the actually files names, so, I need to verify each of the file name's and search for an specific string, for then, group up, but has some rules, like, the group has to be in order name ASC and the general has to have either the ones that doesn't match with an type and the ones with the type in it, for the new versions files. (I need to Do this with pure Javascript)
Examples:

```
types: ["general","picture","document","annotation"]
files: [
         {name:"-t_picture_t-my_vacation.jpg"},
         {name:"-t_document_t-my_curriculum.pdf"},
         {name:"my_favorite_music.mp3"},
         {name:"my_dance_video.mp4"},
         {name:"-t_annotation_t-dont_forget.txt"},
       ]
```

The results expected are something like:

```
[
 {name:"my_dance_video.mp4"},
 {name:"my_favorite_music.mp3"},
 {name:"-t_picture_t-my_vacation.jpg"},
 {name:"-t_document_t-my_curriculum.pdf"},
 {name:"-t_annotation_t-dont_forget.txt"},
]
```

Any questions about, just send a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... a simple algorithm will be something like this

```
const types = ["picture","document","annotation", "general"]
const files = [
         {name:"-t_picture_t-my_vacation.jpg"},
         {name:"-t_document_t-my_curriculum.pdf"},
         {name:"my_favorite_music.mp3"},
         {name:"my_dance_video.mp4"},
         {name:"-t_annotation_t-dont_forget.txt"},
       ]
       
const result = []
const matches = {}

for (const file of files) {
    for (const type of types) {
        if (file.name.includes(type)) {
          result.push(file)
          matches[file.name] = true
        } else if (type == 'general' && !matches[file.name]) {
            result.unshift(file)
        }
    }
}

console.log(result)
```

The downside is that we need to wait with `general` category till the end because only when we complete sorting we can add the rest of items without duplication

Hope that helps for you to kick-start your solution. Enjoy

Comment: It's kind it, but I need the real verification, that is something like ".includes(`-t_${type}_t-`)" because for example, if I have a file with the name general, document, picture etc, but not necessarily is the type of the file, since I'm working with the users I can't rely on expect that the user will not entry a name like this lol, but thank you anyway :)